# Google Translate FIrebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-translation-api

I have built a Firebase Cloud Function on my website (hosted with Firebase) to make a translation request. The request returns a 'parse error'. The firebase support confirmed that the error is with the translation API, while the Firebase Cloud function is working perfectly.

My code involves a simple ajax request to my Firebase Cloud Function, which is working fine. The Cloud Translation API is enabled

Following is the error object -

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (a)
always: ƒ ()
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (a)
readyState: 4
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (a)
statusText: "parsererror"
success: ƒ ()
then: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object
```

EDIT: Here is the code

```
exports.detectLanguage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => { 
  cors(request, response, () => { 
    //,request.body.uuid 

    detectLanguage(request.body.query).then((df_response) => { 
      response.header('Content-Type','application/json'); 
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
      response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); 
      return response.status(200).send(df_response); 
    }).catch(console.error); 
  }); 
});



async function detectLanguage(query) { 
  const request = { 
    parent: translationClient.locationPath(projectId, location), 
    content: query, 
    mimeType: 'text/plain', 
    // mime types: text/plain, text/html 
    sourceLanguageCode: 'en', 
    targetLanguageCode: 'hi' 
  }; 
  // Run request 
  const [response] = await translationClient.detectLanguage(request); 
  console.log(Detected Languages:); 
  for (const language of response.languages) { 
    console.log(Language Code: ${language.languageCode}); 
    console.log(Confidence: ${language.confidence}); 
  } 
contd.. 
}
```

Comment: Viplav, are you able to include your Source-code to help people answer the question more easily? On stackoverflow, people also need resources to come up with answers :)

Comment: Firebase Cloud Function
exports.detectLanguage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => { 
    cors(request, response, () => {
        //,request.body.uuid
        detectLanguage(request.body.query).then((df_response) => {
            response.header('Content-Type','application/json');
            response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
            return response.status(200).send(df_response);
        }).catch(console.error);
        
    });
});

contd..

Comment: async function detectLanguage(query) {

const request = {
    parent: translationClient.locationPath(projectId, location),
    content: query,
    mimeType: 'text/plain', // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    sourceLanguageCode: 'en',
    targetLanguageCode: 'hi'
  };

  // Run request
  const [response] = await translationClient.detectLanguage(request);

  console.log(`Detected Languages:`);
  for (const language of response.languages) {
    console.log(`Language Code: ${language.languageCode}`);
    console.log(`Confidence: ${language.confidence}`);
  }

contd..
}

Comment: declarations on top

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const {TranslationServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v3beta1;
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
const projectId = 'projectID';
const location = 'global';

Comment: Subsequently I make an ajax request, which returns the error stated above

var languageURL = 'deployed cloud functions URL';
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: languageURL,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({query: msg}),
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(err) {
     console.log(err.statusText);
     console.log(err.status);
     console.log(err);
    }

   });

Comment: some of your source code is not legible on the comment. Could you edit the question to include the sourcecode in a legible way. I already included what was possible but still some is missing.

Comment: Oh Sorry, Could you highlight which part? Actually the function above is working fine & I have had that cofirmed from the firebase support. The problem is at the Google Translate API, where there is no support forthcoming.